# How to structure random slope with interactions using glmmTMB in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I am trying to:

- Build a model to investigate the effect of `landcover` (a continuous variable) on `presence` of a species.
- Test if and how this effect changes with `season` (a categorical variable, spring and fall).

However, no animal in my data set has observations in both seasons.

I am using R package **glmmTMB** to estimate a binomial GLMM with random intercept and random slope for animal `ID`, but I don't know how to represent the effects of `landcover` (the variable of interest) and `season` in the model formula.

I have tried these two variations:

#### 1)

```r
glmmTMB(presence ~ landcover:season + (1 | ID) +  (0 + landcover:season | ID),  
        family = binomial(), data = dat.rsf, doFit = FALSE, weights = weight)
```

This one is more intuitive to me, but does not converge. Is that just an indication that I cannot estimate this model with my data? Or is this model not the best way to get at the relationships that I am trying to test?

#### 2)

```r
glmmTMB(presence ~ landcover:season + (1 | ID) +  (0 + landcover | ID), 
        family = binomial(), data = dat.rsf, doFit = FALSE, weights = weight)
```

This converges, but is not as intuitive. Does it make sense to not include the interaction in the random slope when I include it as a fixed effect? Or does that violate the principle of a random slope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I would suggest

```r
glmmTMB(presence ~ landcover*season + (1 + landcover | ID), 
        family = binomial(), data = dat.rsf, 
         weights = weight,
         map = list(theta=factor(c(NA, 1, 2))),
         start = list(theta = c(log(1e3), rep(0, 2))
    )
```

(noting that `landcover` is a *continuous* predictor).

- If you're using this for habitat selection analysis and need to fix the values of some parameters, see e.g. [here](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/204737/Otters_SSF.r?sequence=39&isAllowed=y) and search for "one-step way" to see how to use the `map` and `start` parameters to achieve your goal ... what I've done here is to fix the *intercept* variation among individuals to a large value (SD=1000). The other two parameters in `theta` are the (among-individual variation in land cover effects, and the correlations between intercept and slope.
- You *can* separate `(1|ID)` and `(0+landcover|ID)`; this will estimate intercept and landcover-effect variation, but assume tha they are independent for each individual. That's not a ridiculous assumption, but the model listed here is more general. `diag(landcover|ID)` is equivalent to `(1|ID) + (0+landcover|ID)`
- including `season` as a term as in `season|ID` doesn't work because it's not possible to estimate among-individual variation in season effects when no individuals are observed in multiple seasons
- As for `landcover:season`: in general, it doesn't make sense to include an interaction term without including the main effects. `landcover*season` is equivalent to `landcover + season + landcover:season`, and would be preferred. (There are sometimes reasons to *violate marginality* by including interactions without their corresponding main effects, but if you're going to do this you should know exactly why you're doing it ...)

Comment: Thank you so much. My landcover variables are actually all continuous (either distances or proportions), will this affect the choice between landcover:season vs. `landcover*season`? In regards to the notation`(1|ID)` and `(0+landcover|ID)`, I am actually following the methods recommended by Muff et al. 2019 and their accompanying [code](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/204737/Goats_RSF.R?sequence=20&isAllowed=y) in order to include both a random intercept and random slope by ID. Is this just two ways of writing the same thing?

Comment: I'll change my answer to reflect the fact that `landcover` is continuous. It does change things a little bit.